# Downloading and loading a CSV file using commandline PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm developing a plugin and I would like to download this CSV
https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/active_fire/c6/csv/MODIS_C6_South_America_7d.csv
and then access the data to create a point shapefile with the create points dot table tool, using PyQGIS command lines in the Python terminal.

Using the download file tool it saves the CSV in the folder C:/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/outputs/

I also wanted to know how to access AppData/Roaming/QGIS... passing through the USER, since it changes from computer to computer.

Comment: Have you tried something with Python already? Can you be so kind and show us a snippet of your code? Should it be a separate class in your plugin or it is a part of a different class?

Answer (score 2):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602931/basic-http-file-downloading-and-saving-to-disk-in-python

```
import urllib.request, os
f = r'https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/active_fire/c6/csv/MODIS_C6_South_America_7d.csv'
savedFile = r'/home/bera/Downloads/{0}'.format(os.path.basename(f))
urllib.request.urlretrieve(f, savedFile)

uri = 'file:/{0}?type=csv&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=longitude&yField=latitude&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no'.format(savedFile)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'my_layer', 'delimitedtext')
#do whatever you want with the layer

QgsProject().instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

[image]